# Is it possible to have microservices with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, osgi, karaf, fabric8

I'm confused about how I can use multiple micro services made with spring boot.

When I read about [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/documentation.html), they always use Blueprint instead of Spring and I don't get the impression that it's possible to use it with Spring boot.

Then I found [Fabric8](http://fabric8.io/) but I cannot find any example of micro services made with Spring boot.

All I need is being able to do hot deployment and configuration at runtime like Karaf does but with multiple Spring boot services.

Is it possible?

Could anybody give me documentation or a project sample?

Thank you

Comment: should this question rather be on programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Read this article from source: https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring  with battery included.

Comment: @Alex, if this question is about Spring, then no.  If this question is about microservices, then maybe.  But, this question is about Spring, so no.

Comment: @Alex I wasn't sure. I will let a moderator move my question if needed

Comment: @DoNhuVy Oh that looks perfect! I will read asap

Comment: @DoNhuVy Do you know if it provides features like karaf? ie hot deployment, configuration at runtime, web console?

Comment: check devtools:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html

Comment: @Marc I don't know about `Karaf` and hot deployment.

Comment: @Alex this question is a poor fit for Programmers, see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @DoNhuVy I think it's gonna be possible with SpringCloud with ConfigurationProperty annotation. I will have to try it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a [demo video showing how to create a Spring Boot microservice](https://vimeo.com/jbossdeveloper/review/170830750/b3c8467593) in the [Fabric8 Microservices Platform](http://fabric8.io/) and having a complete [Continuous Deployment pipeline](http://fabric8.io/guide/cdelivery.html) get created to do the following:

- package the code, create the docker image and kubernetes manifest
- perform system/integration tests
- deploy to the staging environment with rolling updates
- wait for (optional) human approval
- deploy to the production environment with rolling updates

Any code or configuration change in the git repository kicks off rolling updates automatically - which is a form of hot deployment. e.g. if you are running 3 containers in production; new containers are spun up with the new code and/or config based on the rolling upgrade policy. Typically new containers start; when they are ready old ones are taken down, say 1 at a time (or you can do them all at once if you prefer). The rolling upgrade is included in any service load balancing; so new containers only get invoked when they are *ready*.

Given your use of OSGi you may want the containers to keep running and just mutate on the fly. Firstly the whole move to immutable infrastructure (e.g. docker images) means software gets simpler and easier to reason about. Rather than rolling new bundles/code/config in/out on the fly you just make a new image and spin that up.

Mutating on the fly leads to multi-threaded code having to stop and restart services on the fly which can cause all kinds of complex hard to reproduce bugs and resource leaks as you have large complex object dependency graphs of services starting/stopping on the fly. On the Fuse team we've wasted many man years fixing bugs in *restart* logic and I'm sure there's still a zillion bugs hidden there in restarting OSGi services on the fly.

So my preference really is to use a [Continuous Deployment pipeline](http://fabric8.io/guide/cdelivery.html) to roll out all changes; whether code or configuration. Sure there's some latency added between the time you make a change and the moment a process is processing a new request with the new code/config - but you have more quality and reliability baked in. Plus its trivial to roll back. You can also easily do rolling upgrades of the change; so you get fast feedback if the change breaks things for a small subset of your users/traffic rather than a big bang.

That being said; if you still really really want production JVMs to reload code and/or config on the fly without testing it first in a big bang approach with no easy rollback; there are still some options available. They are described in the [configuration microservices documentation](http://fabric8.io/guide/develop/configuration.html).

Essentially it boils down to using a [ConfigMap in Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/) or a [git repository volume](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#gitrepo); in both cases the configuration is exposed as volumes (files) - the Java code can then watch the files and reload on the fly. You can do this via OSGi Config Admin or via [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-hotswapping) - whichever development framework you pick really.

Just remember the tradeoff of the benefits in latency from hot-reloading from the reduced quality, increased bugs and operational issues of moving away from immutable infrastructure and Continuous Delivery

Comment: Completely agreed, especially in a Microservices world, where turnaround times are supposed to be quick because of the smaller artefact footprints. It should to be affordable to restart whole (micro) apps in order to get to a well defined, always reproducible state. And since it mirrors the way applications are operated in production its a more realistic workflow.

But this only works really well if development roundtrip times can be kept short, which is imho a key requirement.

Comment: I agree that hot deployment is not necessary to have short dev cycles. I personally work with OSGi in the same way as James showed for spring boot. I create fully packaged deployment units in an automated pipeline. 

The main difference is that I propose to not start with microservices but rather a modular application in one process. It is much simpler. Then if needed you split out the modules with different team or dev cycles as individual microservices.

Answer (score 4):

You can not get hot deployment working with spring boot. We are currently working on karaf boot which aims to provide a spring boot like experience in OSGi.

I also did a talk at a conference in Barcelona (JBCNCONF) last week that covers this topic: [Lean microservices in OSGi](http://www.slideshare.net/ChristianSchneider3/lean-microservices-on-osgi).

So I think microservices in OSGi are already viable but we are not yet at the same convenience that spring boot provides.

Comment: I'm confused about OSGI. I thought it was spec to create a bundle of module(microservices)

Comment: That is true. OSGi allows to create modular applications and these communicate through OSGi services (also called microservices). Spring is not very compatible to OSGi though and also not very modular. So the spring boot way is to create each microservice as its own deployment unit and let them communicate using REST or similar.

So both do modules but in a very different way.

Comment: How to use/deploy Spring-boot in karaf.

Comment: Spring boot does not work in karaf. Karaf and OSGi provide means of creating micro services but this is not compatible to spring boot.